# Swipe the views in a popupView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swipe

Is it possible to create a popupView which shows a different ViewController and allows swiping through the other ViewControllers and when taping one viewController it opens the tapped ViewController?

If yes, how would it work to show the different ViewControllers in this popUpView?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use container views and UIViewController containment API to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to edit the question to how it would be possible to be able to tap a viewController and get to this ViewController I tapped.
But you was faster than me.

Would you answer that too, please?